# jQuery get input value not working on first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I'm trying to get input value using jQuery, but it's not working on first instance when the button is pressed. It only works when I press back button to get back to this page:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control email_input" name='email' id="reserve_email_1" placeholder="Enter your email">
<button type="submit" id="subscribe_1" class="btn btn-success subscribe_button">Get now</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#subscribe_1').click(function(){
    var email_1 = $('#reserve_email_1').text();

    alert(email_1);
});
```

When I type something into the input and press the button, the alert shows an empty message, it then redirects to another page (it redirects since it's part of a form), then I press the back button again to go back to this page where the same text is left in the input, and this time when I press the button the alert message shows up with the text I put in. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Your code doesn't indicate why this might be happening in your case. Please some code that reproduces the issue. Your code has nothing to do with history or that could be affected by caching.

Comment: see browser console, is there any error or warning when hit button? maybe the submit button is problem,use preventDefault in onClick and post from with jqeury

Answer (score 0):

An input doesn't have text, it's a self closing element, it does however have value

```
$('#subscribe_1').click(function(){
    var email_1 = $('#reserve_email_1').val();

    alert(email_1);
});
```

[**jQuery.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: The asker claims his code works after a browser back. Why would it be?

Comment: @JanDvorak - Have no idea, but surely you can't get an inputs value with `text()`, so something else is probably interfering, but it sounds very very strange that it suddenly works when hitting the back button when the OP is clearly using the wrong method ?

Comment: and text() does get me the value of the input

Comment: Then there's an issue, you must have another element with that ID or something as `text` does **not** get the value of an input, a simple [test](http://jsfiddle.net/J6agK/) can determine that. If `text` is working, it's not an input you're getting the text from.